# Random generator

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to find a c function that generates a 32bit random/pseudo random number and can be reproduced. (Like the rand/srand functions). I cannot use urandom because I cannot reproduce the sequence like I can with srand/rand. Do I have to write my own function or does something like this already exist?

Thanks

For future reference, while the suggestions by others were good. I ended up by doing something like this:

```
uint32_t generateRandom (unsigned int randomSeed) {
   uint32_t number = 0;
   int randomNumber, x;

   for (x=0; x<8;x++) {
       randomNumber = rand_r(&randomSeed) % 16;
       number |= (randomNumber<<(x*4));
       randomSeed++;
   }
   return (number);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use rand / srand?

Comment: Which of your requirements rules out using `rand`/`srand`?

Comment: I'm trying to write to some memory locations (trying to turn certain bits on and off) for that I need to generate a 32bit integer, rand/srand only accept a unsigned long int...this is giving me a very small number.

Comment: Your solution (the edited post) with `number |= ...` is going to generate non-uniform distribution (some numbers are more likely to be chosen than others). Use `number ^= ...` instead.

Comment: Hi pmg, I'm confused on how the distribution would be non-random. I'm just OR-ing to get the 4 random bytes in there, why would an XOR be more advantageous here? I'm really intrigued, please answer! Thanks.

Comment: @Falcata your algorithm would indeed return a *pseudo random* number, but not all results would be equally likely, b/c results with many bits set would be more likely than results with few bits set. So the result *7* would be drastically more likely than *8*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join 2 (or more) `rand()` results to obtain as many digits as you need.
Bad (because it's exaggerated) example:

```
uint32_t bit0 = rand() & 1;
uint32_t bit1 = rand() & 1;
/* ... */
uint32_t bit31 = rand() & 1;

uint32_t whole = bit0 | (bit1 << 1) | ... | (bit31 << 31);
```

Comment: Thank you! But a little too late :P I ended up doing something similar (see edit) much thanks though :)

Answer (score 2):

Any [Linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) or [Lagged Fibonacci generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagged_Fibonacci_generator) will do. Google will find you plenty minimal implementations.

As pointed out in the comments, the C standard function [`srand`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/rand.html) + `rand` will work just fine, too, so you should use that.

Answer (score 2):

The way that a lot of these functions are written is a variant of a [linear feedback shift register](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register). If you feel like you want to write your own, I'd do something like this.

Answer (score 2):

RAND_MAX is 2147483647 on linux, so if you don't want to scale up rand() (and eliminate half the possibilities), use [mrand48](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/3/mrand48/)() and interpret the return value as an unsigned long

Answer (score 2):

From your comments on your question, I can't fathom why you are not using `rand()` and `srand()`. Is it because they aren't in the right range? If so, do something like:

```
uint32_t random_num;
int i, random_byte;
srand(SEED_VALUE);

random_num = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    random_byte = rand() & 0xff;
    random_num = (randum_num << 8) + random_byte;
}
```

Not the most efficient code possible, but reasonably fast and should do what you want.